# Can BGV scheme work with congruent values

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Since all evaluation in BGV scheme is on polynomials it seems that it does not really matter if the coefficients of the polynomials are within $q$ range or not. All must be okay for the congruent values.

I have the following questions:

1. If there are no specific optimizations (e.g. RNS) for BGV, can we work in modulo $Kq$, where $K$ is some arbitrary number? Let us ignore encryption/decryption and focus only on adversary side evaluations: additions/multiplications.
2. If the answer to question 1 is yes, then what optimizations can be affected or broken by working in $Kq$?
3. Is it the same for BFV scheme?

Comment: Oddy has indicated that the Q is fine now. And yes, this is just a message to bump it up after 3 days of being hidden.